# Product of integers

Tags: numerics

Find the product of the first 100 integers. Assign this value to a variable called product100.

So how would I input the product of the first 100 integers in free-form?

Comment: have you tried looking up product under help?

Comment: `WolframAlpha["product of first 100 integers"]` or `WolframAlpha["100 factorial"]` or `Factorial[100]` or `100!`

Comment: `product100 = 
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 
73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 
96 97 98 99 100`

Answer (score 9):

The product of consecutive integers from `1` up to `n` is called a `Factorial` ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)). One can use `Factorial[100]` to get the product of the first 100 integers; the shorthand notation for a `Factorial` is with an exclamation mark: `100!` is the same as `Factorial[100]`. Hence, typing in Mathematica

```
product100 = 100!
```

> 9332621544394415268169923885626670049071596826438162146859296389521759
>   9993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000
>   000000000000000000

---

This is the same as

```
Product[i, {i, 100}]
```

Answer (score 7):

First you create a `List` of the first 100 integers using [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html),

```
list = Range[100]

(*
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
 <<61>>,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100}
*)
```

Internally, this is stored as `List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ........99, 100]`, and you need to convert it to `Times[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,.......99, 100]` and the way to do that is to use `Apply`:

```
Apply[Times, list]

(* 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000 *)
```

In shorthand, you can just enter `Times @@ Range[100]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @corey979 told, continuous form of `Factorial` functions is `Gamma` function such that `Gamma[n+1]==Factorial[n]` so use this:

```
Gamma[101]
```